# Hard Color Stop in Linear Transition

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using the following css to style my webpage:

body{background:linear-gradient(180deg, #002e56 29px, #fff 30px)}

It works great, it gives me a dark blue bar 29px tall that runs across the top of a white page and it allows me to easily change colors later.

The only problem I've run across is Chrome on Android. Instead of having a sharp edge, it gives me a smooth color transition from dark blue to white.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How big is the *transition* area? Is it 1px? If yes, try changing the color stop point from 29px to 30px.

Comment: Ideally there wouldn't be a transition area, it would be one solid color butted up against another solid color. I'd be cool with just a 1px transition if I had to, but Chrome on Android is giving it like a 25px transition area.

Comment: That's interesting because as per your code it shouldn't be showing 2.5px transition area but unfortunately I don't have any Android devices and so can't help much.

Comment: Looks like its a known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140208